# Process Builder firing when it shouldn't

Tags: process-builder, case, email-alert

This PB seems to be firing despite not meeting (the intended) criteria and can't figure out what I'm missing.

Image - Criteria says when Status = NEW and OwnerID =! a specific user, yet an email is being fired when that user is OwnerID.

[image]

Anyone know why it's firing?

Comment: Is there a chance of another automation happening on case owner field?

Comment: Can you update with the criteria for waiting and urgent? May be any of the three criteria getting fullfiled..  Thats why it is getting fired

Comment: Enable debug logs and check the log which criteria is getting fullfiled

Answer (score 1):

Process Builder seems to be a bit inconsistent in when it uses 15-digit vs. 18-digit IDs. I've found that when using them in conditions, the 18-digit version must be used. There are a number of ways to do this conversion, but you can use [this tool](https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/15to18) to grab the 18-digit version of the OwnerId in question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not entirely straight forward to test time-based PB's, I think I may have found the fix, but we'll see in about a couple days.

There were a queue of flows not yet executed and from my research it seems that time-based flows only get evaluated once and if it doesn't meet the criteria of an updated Process Builder it will still fire. So I had to go to Setup | Create | Flows | Scroll down to paused/waiting interviews and delete all the flows in the queue.